# How To tune alfresco solr4

Tags: solr4, alfresco-webscripts

I have 1000+folders in my alfresco-5.2 and every folder has 10+ files.Approximately 20-30 thousand documents are there.I want to get the number of files with specific doc type present in folders.So i am querying with solr4. for one folder it's taking 2-3 sec so for all folder it's taking 50 min to 60 min.Can anyone tell me how to tune alfresco solr4 to reduce response time.

Comment: How are you querying? What's your infrastructure?

Comment: My query -- > cm:name:* AND TYPE:"doctype" AND PATH:"path of the folders"

Infrastructure -- >
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,
14GB ram, 
8 core cpu,
solr4,
alfresco-5.2

Comment: And i am using searchService

  SearchParameters parameters = new SearchParameters();
  parameters.addStore(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE);
  parameters.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_FTS_ALFRESCO);
  parameters.setQuery(searchQuery);
  parameters.setNamespace(Model.NAMESPACE_VMR_CONTENT_MODEL);

results = searchService.query(parameters);

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding PATH search if you can all together (it's slow). Also, "cm:name:*" part of the query does nothing basically.  Further more, try using Lucene rather then FTS.

Comment: Basically i have to show the count of the particular doctype in all folders so for that i am using 
  i need something like this 
myFolder(3)
newFolder(5)
@Lista

Comment: Why don't you try using folder as a starting point (find the folder node first), then call getChildrenByAspect method on it and get the number from there?

Comment: that is taking more time then querying with solr4

Comment: http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/node/search?q=cm:name:* AND TYPE:"vmr:unindexed" AND PATH:"/app:company_home/cm:CORP_196//*"&lang=fts-alfresco&store=workspace://SpacesStore&maxResults=10000    alfresco is using this api to get the result from solr and it's quiet fast but that needs Alfresco-CSRFToken  details to authorize can you tell me how to use this in my java backed api's?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link it has useful information about how many document are created by user and other filters are also there.

https://angelborroy.wordpress.com/2017/07/18/extrating-simple-stats-from-alfresco-5/